# Content deployer error when publishing to Oracle broker db

Tags: oracle, tridion

I'm getting an error when trying to deploy content to an oracle broker database (I'm running Tridion 2011 sp1).  I've had a search on the SDL Tridion forum and cannot find anyone that's had the same issue.

The error message in the cme is:

```
Committing Deployment Failed
 Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-55-66560,
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, 
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, Unable to prepare transaction:
  tcm:0-55-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, 
  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

And in the deployer logs i get the following:

```
2012-02-24 15:07:27,866 WARN  DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failure message: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-55-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query for transaction: tcm:0-55-66560
2012-02-24 15:07:27,866 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Failure in Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase attempt: 11 for transaction: tcm:0-55-66560
2012-02-24 15:07:27,866 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-55-66560
2012-02-24 15:07:27,875 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-55-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-55-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:120) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:417) [na:1.5.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:269) [na:1.5.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:123) [na:1.5.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650) [na:1.5.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675) [na:1.5.0_11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595) [na:1.5.0_11]
2012-02-24 15:07:27,875 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-55-66560
2012-02-24 15:07:27,876 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-55-66560
2012-02-24 15:07:27,880 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Checking if transaction is completed: tcm:0-55-66560 is true
2012-02-24 15:07:27,880 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Transaction is completed: tcm:0-55-66560
2012-02-24 15:07:27,882 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-55-66560 in 2274 ms.
```

EDIT:

Here is the  node from the cd_storage_conf.xml file:

```
<Storages>
    <Storage Type="persistence" Id="ddeploy" dialect="ORACLESQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
                <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="secret"/>
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1526"/>
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="secret"/>
                <Property Name="user" Value="secret"/>
                <Property Name="password" Value="secret"/>
            </DataSource>
    </Storage> 

    <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="/htdocs/en_US/" />
    </Storage>

    <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
        <Root Path="/htdocs/en_US/data" />
    </Storage>
</Storages>
```

And the item types

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="ddeploy" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi John.  Which Oracle version (and patch) are you using?  Is it all content that is failing to deploy (I suspect that this is the case) or just a certain type?

Comment: Have you checked that your lib folder contains the correct JAR file for your version of Java?  (ojdbc5.jar for Java 5  and  ojdbc6.jar for Java 6)

Comment: hey Jonathan - its everything to db.  Jar's are all fine.  thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! - I can confirm the issue here was that the oracle database user did not have access to the correct schema.

Still if anyone searches here for the same issue, they'll know the correct place to look :)

Comment: Thanks for the update John.  It is strange that Hibernate (or Oracle) returned a SQLGrammarException rather than some kind of authentication failure message.  One to watch out for!

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the SQL query generated by hibernate doesn't execute properly on your database. Can you double check your storage config (perhaps post the <Storage/> element here. In particular, can you check that the dialect attribute is correct.

Comment: Hi Dom, i've added the storages node to my question.  thanks.